# How to install Flash player plugin on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, adobe-flash

Anyone have a recommended way to get and install Flash effectively on Fedora?

Comment: Which version of Fedora?

Comment: You can check this [link](http://www.linuxstall.com/howtoinstallflashplayerlinux/) for installation steps, it includes Fedora as well as Red Hat and CentOS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adobe’s Flash plugin is not included in Fedora because it is not free. Adobe has released a version of the Flash plugin for Linux.

### Enabling Flash Plugin

To begin, refer to the Adobe site at http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/
This will download the adobe-release-i386-1.0-1.noarch.rpm file. Issue the following command within the directory where you have downloaded the repository rpm file.

```
su -c ‘rpm -ivh adobe-release-i386-1.0-1.noarch.rpm’
```

The .rpm file also copies the adobe General Public Key (GPG key) to /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-adobe-linux but does not import it. To import the key, type:

```
su -c ‘rpm –import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-adobe-linux’
```

The system is now ready to fetch rpm packages from adobe using yum. To verify this, take a look at the /etc/yum.repos.d/adobe-linux-i386.repo file that was just created. You should see something similar to the following:

```
adobe-linux-i386]
name=Adobe Systems Incorporated
baseurl=http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/linux/i386/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-adobe-linux
```

Notice that the file contains the URL where the packages are located, whether or not the repository should be enabled, whether rpm should check downloaded packages from adobe against the GPG key, and the location of the key itself.

Now proceed to either the instructions for 32-bit (i386) platforms(I assume that..)

**On 32-bit Fedora**

After completing the adobe repository configuration, run the following command to install the Flash plugin and ensure sound is enabled:

```
su -c ‘yum install flash-plugin alsa-plugins-pulseaudio \
libcurl’
```

You may see messages indicating that alsa-plugins-pulseaudio and libcurl are already installed. This is not a problem. Note also that nspluginwrapper is installed by default and will wrap the Flash plugin. If you have upgraded from a previous version of Fedora, make sure that nspluginwrapper is installed and the latest version:

```
su -c ‘yum install nspluginwrapper’
```

Next, you should check the plugin.

**Checking the plugin**

After the installation, exit all copies of Firefox and start it again to enable the plugin. Then type the following text in the Firefox address bar:

```
about:plugins
```

This information tells you that the Adobe Flash plugin has been successfully installed.